# This value in object for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, game-development

I'm trying to create 2D array of brick game. how I get `this` value of object that at defining stage, if I use this code,it returned `undefined`

```
const bricks = [];
for (let r = 0; r < brickRow; r++) {
  bricks[r] = []
for (let c = 0; c < brickCol; c++) {
    bricks[r][c] = {
      x:r*(brickWidth+gap)+10,
      y:c*(brickHeight+gap)+10,
      bLeft:this.x,
      bTop:this.y,
      bRight:this.x+brickWidth,
      bBottom:this.y+brickHeight
    }
}
```

accessing via `bricks[r][c].x` inside object not work

use `x` failed, it was global x, not the item brick I want

Comment: What is `this` supposed to be here?

Comment: I need to get the value of previous object property. but sadly no object closure, I thought it same in Class or Function closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have some undefined variables
I hope you really set them out Example: **brickRow**

Second you can set the X and Y outside from the object and use that property
This is not a correct way to use your porperty on the same object where you set it.

```js
const bricks = [];
let brickRow,brickCol,brickWidth,brickHeight,gap;
for (let r = 0; r < brickRow; r++) {
  bricks[r] = []
for (let c = 0; c < brickCol; c++) {
  let xTemp=r*(brickWidth+gap)+10;
  let yTemp=c*(brickHeight+gap)+10;
    bricks[r][c] = {
      x:xTemp,
      y:yTemp,
      bLeft:xTemp,
      bTop:yTemp,
      bRight:xTemp+brickWidth,
      bBottom:yTemp+brickHeight
    }
} 
}
```

Comment: thank you, this worked. simple than object getter

Answer (score 0):

this is undefined because this refers to this object when you call the method. You can explore more about it at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp)

and to solve your problem, just:

```
const bricks = [];
for (let r = 0; r < brickRow; r++) {
      bricks[r] = []
    for (let c = 0; c < brickCol; c++) {
      const x = r*(brickWidth+gap)+10;
      const y = c*(brickHeight+gap)+10;
        bricks[r][c] = {
          x:x,
          y:y,
          bLeft:x,
          bTop:y,
          bRight:x+brickWidth,
          bBottom:y+brickHeight
        }
    } 
    }
```

hope it will help you.Let me know your result